# How to avoid multiple messageboxes continuous display?

Tags: c#, wpf, messagebox

I have a problem with WPF MessageBox,its due to when internet connection is not available. I need the message to displays once only, but it shows multiple times.

```
 private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(cc);
    }
    void cc(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = e.ExceptionObject as Exception;
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Uncaught", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
```

Comment: You need to remove that `while` from the code you showed.

Comment: Oh, then my crystal ball is broken - how should we help if you dont share your code?

Comment: @dognose:see my code am used

Comment: Help me to solve this problem

Comment: `UnhandledException` is fired every time there is some unhandled exception. So looks like you have many continuous unhandled exceptions. You should look into them and try fix them from throwing if possible. This kind of event is used only for some really unexpected exception. Not a recommended way to handle known exceptions which can be done using try-catch.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Simple.
You should confirm before you show message box.

```
// message box flag.
bool canIShowMessageBox = true;

// for thread lock.
object exLocker = new object();    

void cc(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
   lock(exLocker)
   {
      if (canIShowMessageBox)
         canIShowMessageBox = false;
      else
         return;
   }
   Exception ex = e.ExceptionObject as Exception;
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Uncaught", MessageBoxButton.OK);

   lock(exLocker)
      canIShowMessageBox = true;
}
```

Comment: @RajnathKumar I think, you just copy and paste without managing. The last part, set the flag be true again. You should manage there part. It's just sample.

Comment: :Is that canIShowMessageBos=False in last part